# How to execute SBT plugin's tasks from within IntelliJ IDEA CE?

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, sbt

I use [IntelliJ IDEA 13.1 Community Edition](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/IDEADEV/IDEA+13.1+EAP) with the Scala plugin **0.32.593**.

[image]

What's the recommended way to execute a SBT plugin's tasks, say `dependencyUpdates` from [sbt-updates](https://github.com/rtimush/sbt-updates)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**NOTE** IntelliJ IDEA and the Scala and sbt plugins have improved since and you may want to read [How to run sbt-assembly tasks from within IntelliJ IDEA?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25109981/1305344) instead.

I worked it around with the Embedded Terminal plugin that shipped with the version of IDEA.

<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F12</kbd> (or `Tools` > `Open Terminal`) to open a terminal window and then `sbt dependencyUpdates` inside.

[image]

It does require a local installation of SBT.

Comment: IntelliJ 2017.1.1 CE here, the method does not work as SBT is not found. Are you sure you had not sbt already installed system wide?

Comment: I did install sbt locally as said in "It does require a local installation of SBT." (the last sentence). I think you could however use the built-in sbt in 2017.1.1. Haven't checked that out tough.

Answer (score 14):

In version `15` of IntelliJ IDEA, using Scala Plugin version `2.0`, you can run `SBT` tasks by adding a run configuration.

First add a new run configuration by clicking on `Run -> Edit Configurations`. Then click the `+` button to add a new configuration and choose `SBT Task` form the list

[image]

Now provide the list of tasks separated by space in `Tasks` input box:

[image]

Comment: Lets say I want to use the "run" command here. How do I specify the port number?

Comment: Did you try putting the command with the parameters in single quotes or backticks?

Comment: @nader-hadji-ghanbari, putting the SBT Task and its parameters in double quotes ("") was enough to get this working as a configuration, e.g. "test-only my.package.TestClassName" ;-D

Answer (score 2):

Unless there has been a recent change (in 13.1), SBT plugin doesn't support running sbt tasks.

See comments here http://blog.jetbrains.com/scala/2013/11/18/built-in-sbt-support-in-intellij-idea-13/

Answer (score -3):

You will have to run these two commands to run SBT in the terminal:

```
SBT_OPTS="-Xms512M -Xmx1536M -Xss1M -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled -XX:MaxPermSize=256M"
java $SBT_OPTS -jar `<SBT inatall>`/bin/sbt-launch.jar "$@"
```