# How to build an Uber JAR (Fat JAR) using SBT within IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, sbt, meta-inf, uberjar

I'm using SBT (within IntelliJ IDEA) to build a simple Scala project.

I would like to know what is the **simplest way** to build an **Uber JAR** file (aka Fat JAR, Super JAR).

I'm currently using SBT but when I'm submiting my JAR file to [Apache Spark](https://spark.apache.org/) I get the following error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.SecurityException: Invalid
>   signature file digest for Manifest main attributes

Or this error during compilation time:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: deduplicate: different file contents found
>   in the following:
>   PATH\DEPENDENCY.jar:META-INF/DEPENDENCIES
>   PATH\DEPENDENCY.jar:META-INF/MANIFEST.MF

It [looks like](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/spark-developers/1H6bfiCeTaY) it is because some of my dependencies include signature files (META-INF) which needs to be removed in the final Uber JAR file.

I tried to use the [sbt-assembly](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-assembly) plugin like that:

/project/assembly.sbt

```
addSbtPlugin("com.eed3si9n" % "sbt-assembly" % "0.12.0")
```

/project/plugins.sbt

```
logLevel := Level.Warn
```

/build.sbt

```
lazy val commonSettings = Seq(
  name := "Spark-Test"
  version := "1.0"
  scalaVersion := "2.11.4"
)

lazy val app = (project in file("app")).
  settings(commonSettings: _*).
  settings(
    libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
      "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "1.2.0",
      "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-streaming" % "1.2.0",
      "org.apache.spark" % "spark-streaming-twitter_2.10" % "1.2.0"
    )
  )
```

When I click "*Build Artifact...*" in IntelliJ IDEA I get a JAR file. But I end up with the same error...

I'm new to SBT and not very experimented with IntelliJ IDE.

Thanks.

Comment: By the sound of things you may need to filter out the `META-INF` files - one blog post that *might* help: https://janschulte.wordpress.com/2014/03/20/removing-meta-inf-directory-from-sbt-assembly/

Answer (score 158, accepted):

Finally I totally skip using IntelliJ IDEA to avoid generating noise in my global understanding :)

I started reading the [official SBT tutorial](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/tutorial/).

I created my project with the following file structure :

```
my-project/project/assembly.sbt
my-project/src/main/scala/myPackage/MyMainObject.scala
my-project/build.sbt
```

Added the [sbt-assembly](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-assembly) [plugin](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/tutorial/Using-Plugins.html) in my **assembly.sbt** file. Allowing me to build a fat JAR :

```scala
addSbtPlugin("com.eed3si9n" % "sbt-assembly" % "0.12.0")
```

My minimal **build.sbt** looks like :

```scala
lazy val root = (project in file(".")).
  settings(
    name := "my-project",
    version := "1.0",
    scalaVersion := "2.11.4",
    mainClass in Compile := Some("myPackage.MyMainObject")        
  )

val sparkVersion = "1.2.0"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % sparkVersion % "provided",
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-streaming" % sparkVersion % "provided",
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-streaming-twitter" % sparkVersion
)

// META-INF discarding
mergeStrategy in assembly <<= (mergeStrategy in assembly) { (old) =>
   {
    case PathList("META-INF", xs @ _*) => MergeStrategy.discard
    case x => MergeStrategy.first
   }
}
```

*Note*: The [`% "provided"`](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-assembly#-provided-configuration) means not to include the dependency in the final fat JAR (those libraries are already included in my workers)

*Note*: META-INF discarding [inspired by this answser](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28371088/1480391).

*Note*: Meaning of [`%`](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/tutorial/Library-Dependencies.html#Getting+the+right+Scala+version+with) and [`%%`](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/tutorial/Library-Dependencies.html#Getting+the+right+Scala+version+with)

Now I can build my fat JAR using SBT ([how to install it](http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/tutorial/Setup.html)) by running the following command in my **/my-project** root folder:

```
sbt assembly
```

My fat JAR is now located in the new generated **/target** folder :

```
/my-project/target/scala-2.11/my-project-assembly-1.0.jar
```

---

For those who wants to embeed SBT within IntelliJ IDE: [How to run sbt-assembly tasks from within IntelliJ IDEA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25109981/how-to-run-sbt-assembly-tasks-from-within-intellij-idea)

Comment: Java / Maven suggestion on the [problem of excluding Spark from uber-jars from Databricks https://databricks.gitbooks.io/databricks-spark-knowledge-base/content/troubleshooting/missing_dependencies_in_jar_files.htm

Comment: @JimLohse proper link is https://databricks.gitbooks.io/databricks-spark-knowledge-base/content/troubleshooting/missing_dependencies_in_jar_files.html

Comment: What is the reason for discarding old META-INF?

Comment: Note: The % "provided" means not to include the dependency in the final fat JAR is the one helped me!

Comment: seriously surprised that this is *the only* plugin available - not even official, and doesn't even work across sbt versions

Comment: Can this be achieved with a single sbt file, akin to pom.xml?

Comment: Note that operator `<<=` has been removed from newer sbt version, nowadays works by using something like `assemblyMergeStrategy in assembly ~= { _ =>`

Answer (score 43):

3 Step Process For Building Uber JAR/Fat JAR in IntelliJ Idea:

**Uber JAR/Fat JAR** : JAR file having all external libraray dependencies in it.

1. Adding SBT Assembly plugin in IntelliJ Idea
   [image: Plugin sbt Path]

   Go to **ProjectName/project/target/plugins.sbt** file and add this line `addSbtPlugin("com.eed3si9n" % "sbt-assembly" % "0.12.0")`
2. Adding Merge,Discard and Do Not Add strategy in build.sbt
   [image: Build sbt Path]

   Go to **ProjectName/build.sbt** file and add the Strategy for Packaging of an Uber JAR

   **Merge Strategy :** If there is conflict in two packages about a version of library then which one to pack in Uber JAR.
   **Discard Strategy :** To remove some files from library which you do not want to package in Uber JAR.
   **Do not Add Strategy :** Do not add some package to Uber JAR.
   For ex: `spark-core` will be already present at your Spark Cluster.So we should not package this in Uber JAR

   **Merge Strategy and Discard Strategy Basic Code :**

   `assemblyMergeStrategy in assembly := {
          case PathList("META-INF", xs @ _*) => MergeStrategy.discard
          case x => MergeStrategy.first
      }`

   So you are asking to discard META-INF files using this command `MergeStrategy.discard` and for rest of the files you are taking the *first occurrence* of library file if there is any conflict by using this command `MergeStrategy.first`.

   **Do not Add Strategy Basic Code :**

   `libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "1.4.1" %"provided"`

   If we do not want to add the spark-core to our Uber JAR file as it will be already on our clutser, so we are adding the `% "provided"` at end of it library dependency.
3. Building Uber JAR with all its dependencies
   [image: sbtassembly]

   In terminal type `sbt assembly` for building up the package

Voila!!! Uber JAR is built. JAR will be in **ProjectName/target/scala-XX**
[image: JarBuilt]

Answer (score 17):

Add the following line to your project/plugins.sbt

```
addSbtPlugin("com.eed3si9n" % "sbt-assembly" % "0.12.0")
```

Add the following to your build.sbt

```
mainClass in assembly := some("package.MainClass")
assemblyJarName := "desired_jar_name_after_assembly.jar"

val meta = """META.INF(.)*""".r
assemblyMergeStrategy in assembly := {
  case PathList("javax", "servlet", xs @ _*) => MergeStrategy.first
  case PathList(ps @ _*) if ps.last endsWith ".html" => MergeStrategy.first
  case n if n.startsWith("reference.conf") => MergeStrategy.concat
  case n if n.endsWith(".conf") => MergeStrategy.concat
  case meta(_) => MergeStrategy.discard
  case x => MergeStrategy.first
}
```

The Assembly merge strategy is used to resolve conflicts occurred when creating fat jar.

Comment: You can create fat Jar by running "sbt assembly" in console

Comment: for scala version 2.11.8 (SBT version : 0.13.12) put addSbtPlugin("com.eed3si9n" % "sbt-assembly" % "0.12.0") in project/assembly.sbt