# Spark Can't Find JDBC Driver from SBT

Tags: mysql, scala, apache-spark, jdbc

I'm trying to use JDBC in a Scala Spark application, and I'm compiling with sbt. However when I add the line `Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver")`, it throws a ClassNotFoundException.

My sbt file is this:

```
name := "SparkApp"
version := "1.0"
scalaVersion := "2.11.8"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "2.1.0"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % "2.1.0"
libraryDependencies += "com.databricks" %% "spark-csv" % "1.5.0"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-mllib" % "2.1.0"
libraryDependencies += "mysql" % "mysql-connector-java" % "6.0.5"
```

As far as I can tell that last line is all I should need to add the JDBC driver, but it doesn't seem to be working. I've also tried `Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance()` but it has the same result, so I assume the issue is with the jdbc classes not being added correctly at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to supply the class name to use JDBC to load data frames. Following the [Spark SQL documentation](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#jdbc-to-other-databases), you only have to supply `"jdbc"` as the data source format (and indeed add the connector as a dependency) and set the right options:

```
val host: String = ???
val port: Int = ???
val database: String = ???
val table: String = ???
val user: String = ???
val password: String = ???

val options = Map(
      "url" -> s"jdbc:mysql://$host:$port/$database?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull",
      "dbtable" -> table,
      "user" -> user,
      "password" -> password)

val df = spark.read.format("jdbc").options(options).load()
```

When you submit your application to Spark, you have to either include the MySQL connector into your final jar file, or tell `spark-submit` to get the package as a dependency:

```
spark-submit --packages mysql:mysql-connector-java:6.0.5 ...
```

This flag also works on `spark-shell` or `pyspark`.

Comment: What about for writing to the DB? My end goal was to take a DataFrame I have and write that into a table in MySQL. I tried doing that like this, but got a "No suitable driver" error:

`val prop = new java.util.Properties()
prop.setProperty("user", "username")
prop.setProperty("password", "password")
dataFrame.write.mode("append").jdbc("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/database", "table", prop)`

Comment: Writing should work similarly, with the same options. How do you run your code? If you submit it, see my edits on making sure the dependency is available.

Comment: Added that packages argument and that seems to have solved the driver issue. Initially gave a deprecated error but I just had to change to `com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver`. Would have thought that the sbt dependency would be enough. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your mysql driver class *com.mysql.jdbc.Driver* it's not present on your classpath at runtime. If your are running your spark job with *spark-submit* than you have at least two options:

- provide *--jar* options to specify the path for the mysql-*.jar (see this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37132559/add-jars-to-a-spark-job-spark-submit)) (if both worker and driver need the class then take a close look on the *spark.executor.extraJavaOptions* and *spark.driver.extraJavaOptions*)
- build an uber jar (fat jar) that will include your mysql-* classes on your application jar (see this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28459333/how-to-build-an-uber-jar-fat-jar-using-sbt-within-intellij-idea))

Answer (score 0):

`spark-submit \
              --class com.mypack.MyClass \
              --master yarn --deploy-mode cluster \
              --conf spark.executor.extraClassPath=$POSTGRESQL_JAR_PATH:$MYSQL_JAR_PATH \
               --conf spark.driver.extraClassPath=$POSTGRESQL_JAR_PATH:$MYSQL_JAR_PATH \`

where, `$POSTGRESQL_JAR_PATH` and `$MYSQL_JAR_PATH` should be set with hdfs path to jar files.

hope this helps.

`spark.executor.extraClassPath` if you are running it in cluster mode. 
`spark.driver.extraClassPath` if you are running it in local.

I recommend setting both option to be on safer side.

Answer (score 0):

You should pass driver jar while submitting the spark job like below:

1)
spark-submit --jars mysql-connector-java-5.1.39.jar and rest of the parameters as you are passing

2) if you just wanna try on local using shell
spark-shell --jars mysql-connector-java-5.1.39.jar

Update the driver to the one which you already have available and provide the absolute path to that