# Java Spark: com.mongodb.spark.config.writeconfig issue

Tags: java, mongodb, apache-spark, spark-streaming

I am trying to connect with MongoDB via java spark connector and I am getting an error "com.mongodb.spark.config.writeconfig", when I submit the jar and run the jar in spark shell. Here the error screenshot:
[image]

Could you please help me to resolve this issue. I have tried this as well, but no success.

- $./bin/sparkR --conf "spark.mongodb.input.uri=mongodb://127.0.0.1/test.myCollection?readPreference=primaryPreferred" ./bin/sparkR --conf "spark.mongodb.output.uri=mongodb://127.0.0.1/db.test" ./bin/spark-shell --packages org.mongodb.spark:mongo-spark-connector_2.11:2.2.0
- $spark-submit --master local --class com.test.spark.SparkClient /home/otalogin/SparkClient.jar
- $spark-submit --master local --class com.test.spark.SparkClient /home/otalogin/SparkClient.jar --jar mongo-spark-connector_2.11:2.2.0

but getting same error.

Please help me out of this issue.

Comment: Did you try with submitting fat jar to spark?

Comment: No, we just export the JAR from eclipse and submit on a terminal.

Comment: Can you just add an answer how you fixed it i need help as i have the same issue now

Comment: Hi Sundeep, I fix this issue, to fresh setup and download all maven dependencies, then build and check the jar size. it should include all dependent configuration file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by [Darshan M](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3880330/darshan-m), you need to provide mongo dependencies.

The easiest way is to build a fat jar using maven / sbt.

If you use maven, configure your pom.xml, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16222748/building-a-fat-jar-using-maven) can help you. If you use sbt, [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28459333/how-to-build-an-uber-jar-fat-jar-using-sbt-within-intellij-idea) can help you.

Comment: Thanks Bameza and Darshan M, for help. Now everything is working fine as expected.

Comment: please help me in fixing the same