# Run Spark code written in Scala in spark cluster

Tags: scala, hadoop, apache-spark, intellij-idea, bigdata

I have IntelliJ IDE installed in my laptop.
I am trying to do some Bigdata Spark POCs written in Scala.
My requirement is that the spark-scala code written in IntelliJ IDE should run in spark cluster when I click Run. My spark cluster is residing in windows azure cloud.
How can I achieve this?

Comment: The usual method is to generate a fat jar using a sbt-assembly plugin, copy the jar to the spark cluster's master node, ssh to the node and run it using spark-submit. You can definitely do the first step within IntelliJ - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28459333/how-to-build-an-uber-jar-fat-jar-using-sbt-within-intellij-idea. Do you need the other steps to happen within IntelliJ as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to create a script to run the jar file created, and run that script.

And another way it touse Azure Toolkit plugin.

You can use [Azure Toolkit for IntelliJ](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/8053-azure-toolkit-for-intellij) Intellij Idea plugin to submit, run debug the spark application

Search and install the plugin as below

[image]

To submit and run the application you can follow the documentation here

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/hdinsight-tool-for-intellij-is-ga/

[Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/hdinsight/spark/apache-spark-intellij-tool-plugin) is the example 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/hdinsight/spark/apache-spark-intellij-tool-plugin

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank You Shankar...I Am going through the links and seems like this is what i was looking for.

Comment: Great that helped you, I am working with the azure and spark but I don't use the plugins, I just use scripts to run.

Comment: I was trying to link the HDinsight cluster. but got the error.Authentication Error: Socket operation on nonsocket: connect. Any Idea why this happens.

Comment: Can you provide the alternative method. i.e running through scripts

Comment: I am not sure with the error, Script is to write all the steps that we manually do when submitting the jar to Azure cluster.

Comment: is there a similar setup for pyspark/python.

Answer (score 0):

step 1:before starting the process you have to download the hadoop bin

https://github.com/steveloughran/winutils/tree/master/hadoop-2.6.0/bin

and you have to set the hadoop home in environment variables example:C:\Hadoop\hadoop

Step2:Then Download the spark of desired version

add the path C:\Hadoop\spark-1.6.0-bin-hadoop2.6\bin to environment variables

step3: open cmd and go to spark folder till bin 
        C:\Hadoop\spark-1.6.0-bin-hadoop2.6\bin and type following command spark-class org.apache.spark.deploy.master.Master
        it will give the spark master ip like example spark://localhost:7077
step4:open another cmd and go to spark folder till bin and type following command spark-class org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker SparkMasterIp

step5: To check it is working or not we can test by below command
    C:\Hadoop\spark-1.6.0-bin-hadoop2.6\bin\spark-shell -master masterip

now you can build your jar and submit the jar to spark-submit from cmd