# SBT run - Pass dependencies to worker nodes for a spark job

Tags: apache-kafka, sbt, spark-structured-streaming

I have a streaming job running using SBT.

whenever i do "sbt run", i see below error. I see it is because workers are not able to get the required kafka dependency.

Is there a way of passing the dependency jars along with sbt run command?

ERROR:

```
Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 1 in stage 13.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 1.3 in stage 13.0 (TID 227, 10.148.9.12, executor 1): java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.KafkaContinuousDataReaderFactory
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaDeserializationStream$$anon$1.resolveClass(JavaSerializer.scala:67)
```

build.sbt:

```
name := "MyAPP"
version := "0.5"
scalaVersion := "2.11.8"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "2.3.1",
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % "2.3.1",
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-streaming" % "2.3.1",
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-streaming-kafka-0-10" % "2.3.1",
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql-kafka-0-10" % "2.3.1",
  "com.typesafe" % "config" % "1.3.2",
  "org.apache.logging.log4j" % "log4j-api" % "2.11.0",
  "org.apache.logging.log4j" % "log4j-core" % "2.11.0",
  "org.apache.logging.log4j" %% "log4j-api-scala" % "11.0",
  "org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % "3.0.5" % "test",
  "org.apache.kafka" % "kafka_2.11" % "0.10.2.2",
  "org.apache.kafka" % "kafka-clients" % "0.10.2.2",
  "ml.combust.mleap" %% "mleap-runtime" % "0.11.0",
  "com.typesafe.play" % "play-json_2.11" % "2.6.10",
  "com.fasterxml.jackson.module" % "jackson-module-scala_2.11" % "2.8.11",
  "net.liftweb" %% "lift-json" % "3.3.0"
)

lazy val excludeJpountz = ExclusionRule(organization = "net.jpountz.lz4", name = "lz4")
lazy val kafkaClients = "org.apache.kafka" % "kafka-clients" % "0.10.2.2" excludeAll(excludeJpountz)

logBuffered in Test := false

fork in Test := true

// Don't run tests before assembling
test in assembly := {}

retrieveManaged := true

assemblyMergeStrategy in assembly := {
  case "META-INF/services/org.apache.spark.sql.sources.DataSourceRegister" => MergeStrategy.concat
  case PathList("META-INF", xs@_*) => MergeStrategy.discard
  case "log4j.properties" => MergeStrategy.discard
  case x => MergeStrategy.first`enter code here`
}

unmanagedBase := baseDirectory.value / "lib"
```

Comment: I doubt you need *all* of Kafka, including the server... `"org.apache.kafka" % "kafka_2.11" % "0.10.2.2",` but you need to create an uber JAR, which I don't know if SBT does by default and you must add `provided` on the Spark Core,Streaming,SQL lines https://stackoverflow.com/a/28498443/2308683

Comment: Why do you `sbt run` to execute the Spark app? Why not `spark-submit --packages` that would take care of this issue?