# How to write a java class with main method to forward to my scala code?

Tags: java, scala

Let me preface by saying I am not very good at programming. Here I have a wordCount Scala code and I want to run as a JAR file for which I need to have a Java class with a main method forwarded to it.

I have created a class but I'm not sure where and how to place it

```
public class Class{
  object SparkWordCount {
    public static void main(args: Array[String]) {
      val sc = new SparkContext(new SparkConf().setAppName("Spark Count"))
    }
  }
}
```

I want to create a Java class to my Scala code and run it as a JAR file.

Comment: Where is your Scala code? Is there a method in there that you want to call? Or, if it is packaged as a Spark job already, can you run it using the normal tools to submit Spark jobs?

Comment: This is very unclear what the problem is. I suspect the answer might be to follow some of the getting started with spark and java tutorials such as this one (which I picked randomly from the many Google search results)... https://www.geekmj.org/insights/java-getting-started-725/

Comment: My scala code is just a wordCount. All I want to do is call it as a java application hence I tried to write it as a Java class

Comment: Can you explain why you want to call it as a *Java* application rather than a *Scala* application? What is the actual problem that you are trying to solve?

Comment: So I want to run it as a JAR file because I need to deploy it in EMR cluster which only takes JAR files. All I need is to write a Java class with main method which forwards the call to my Scala code

Comment: Again, why? A Scala application can host a main.

Comment: And Scala code can create JAR files. It doesn't sound like you need Java at all.

Comment: `I want to create a Java class to my Scala code and run it as a JAR file.`

what exactly you want to say O_o ?

Comment: ok so if my scala code can be saved and run as a JAR file can you please tell me how to do this? Sorry I know i seem very stupid but I am new to this

Comment: Use the `scalac` compiler to compile the source files to `.class` files. Then create the JAR file the same way you would with Java `.class` files, usually with the `jar` command.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using [sbt](https://www.scala-sbt.org/) to [package](https://alvinalexander.com/scala/sbt-how-to-compile-run-package-scala-project) your Scala application as a JAR like so

```
sbt package
```

However, this will package only your applications's classes, without the dependencies. Package that includes everything is usually called a **fat JAR** and [`sbt-assembly`](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-assembly) is an sbt plugin that enables creation of such packages like so

```
sbt assembly
```

To create Apache Spark fat jar try exploring the following answer
https://stackoverflow.com/a/28498443/5205022

Try first packaging a simple hello world application before progressing to building fat apache spark jars. For example, [install sbt](https://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Setup.html), and then execute the following command

```
sbt new scala/scala-seed.g8
```

and then try exploring what happens when you execute `sbt package` within the created hello world application. The jar package should end up under `target` directory.