# Unable to connect to Hive server using JDBC connection

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hive

I am trying to connect to Hive server from scala code as below.

```
def getHiveConnection(): Connection = {
    println("Building Hive connection..")
    val driver   = "org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver"
    val user     = "user"
    val pwd      = "pwd
    val url      = "jdbc:hive2://ip-00-000-000-000.ec2.internal:00000/dbname;principal=hive/ip-00-000-000-000.ec2.internal@DEV.COM"
    var connection: Connection = null

    val conf = new Configuration()
    conf.set("hadoop.security.authentication", "Kerberos")
    UserGroupInformation.setConfiguration(conf)

    try {
        println("Setting the driver..")
        Class.forName(driver)
        println("pre connection")
        if((connection == null)  || connection.isClosed()) {
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, pwd)
            println("Hive connection eshtablished.")
        }
    } catch {
        case cnf:ClassNotFoundException => println("Invalid driver used. Check the settings.")
            cnf.printStackTrace()
        case e:Exception => println("Other exception.")
            e.printStackTrace()
    }
    connection
}
```

I create a jar file from the program on IntelliJ and then run the jar using spar-submit as I need to run some sql that is not supported by SPARK.

spark-submit:

```
SPARK_MAJOR_VERSION=2 spark-submit --class com.package.program.Begin --master=yarn --conf spark.ui.port=4090 --driver-class-path /home/username/testlib/inputdir/myjars/hive-jdbc-2.3.5.jar --conf spark.jars=/home/username/testlib/inputdir/myjars/hive-jdbc-2.3.5.jar --executor-cores 4 --executor-memory 4G --keytab /home/username/username.keytab --principal username@DEV.COM --files /$SPARK_HOME/conf/hive-site.xml,connection.properties --name Splinter splinter_2.11-0.1.jar
```

When I submit the code, it fails with the exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hive/service/rpc/thrift/TCLIService$Iface
```

To be precise, the exception comes at the line:

```
connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, pwd)
```

Dependencies I added in the SBT files can be seen below:

```
name := "Splinter"
version := "0.1"
scalaVersion := "2.11.8"
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "2.0.0",
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % "2.0.0",
  "org.json4s" %% "json4s-jackson" % "3.2.11",
  "org.apache.httpcomponents" % "httpclient" % "4.5.3",
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-hive" % "2.0.0",
)
libraryDependencies += "org.postgresql" % "postgresql" % "42.1.4"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.hadoop" % "hadoop-auth" % "2.6.0"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.hadoop" % "hadoop-common" % "2.6.2"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.hadoop" % "hadoop-core" % "1.2.1"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.hadoop" % "hadoop-mapreduce-client-common" % "2.6.5"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.hadoop" % "hadoop-mapreduce-client-core" % "2.6.5"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.hadoop" % "hadoop-mapreduce-client-jobclient" % "2.6.5" % "provided"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.hive" % "hive-jdbc" % "2.3.5"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.hive" % "hive-common" % "2.3.5"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.hive" % "hive-metastore" % "2.3.5"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.hive" % "hive-service" % "2.3.5"
libraryDependencies += "org.slf4j" % "slf4j-api" % "1.7.26"
libraryDependencies += "commons-cli" % "commons-cli" % "1.4"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.hive" % "hive-service-rpc" % "2.1.0"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.hive" % "hive-cli" % "2.3.5"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.hive" % "hive-exec" % "2.3.4" excludeAll
  ExclusionRule(organization = "org.pentaho")
```

Along with the dependencies, I moved all the jars from the dir via `--jars` in spark-submit and that didn't work either.

The full exception stack could be seen below:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hive/service/rpc/thrift/TCLIService$Iface
    at org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver.connect(HiveDriver.java:107)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:270)
    at com.data.stages.ExchangePartition.getHiveConnection(ExchangePartition.scala:30)
    at com.data.stages.ExchangePartition.exchange(ExchangePartition.scala:44)
    at com.partition.source.Pickup$.main(Pickup.scala:124)
    at com.partition.source.Pickup.main(Pickup.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:782)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:180)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:205)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:119)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.hive.service.rpc.thrift.TCLIService$Iface
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 16 more
```

Could anyone let me know what dependencies am I missing in the sbt file ?
If not, what could be the mistake I am doing here since, the same type of code works in Jave with the same libraries(dependencies) in the project and I couldn't understand what is wrong here ?
Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I dont know you are using client or cluster mode for the `spark-submit.`

> Could anyone let me know what dependencies am I missing in the sbt
>   file ?

But dependency which you added is correct.

[`libraryDependencies += "org.apache.hive" % "hive-jdbc" % "2.3.5"`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.hive/hive-jdbc/2.3.5)

I would suggest you to go with uber jar i.e. package all jars with dependencies as one jar so that nothing is missed or left out.

How to make uber jar [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28459333/how-to-build-an-uber-jar-fat-jar-using-sbt-within-intellij-idea)

**Also add this code to your *driver* ... understand what jars are coming in to your classpath.**

```
val  urls = urlsinclasspath(getClass.getClassLoader).foreach(println)


def urlsinclasspath(cl: ClassLoader): Array[java.net.URL] = cl match {
    case null => Array()
    case u: java.net.URLClassLoader => u.getURLs() ++ urlsinclasspath(cl.getParent)
    case _ => urlsinclasspath(cl.getParent)
  }
```

Comment: It's client . By default its client. Would client/cluster mode make any difference?