# How to fix this scala jar error "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/spark/sql/types/DataType"

Tags: scala, apache-spark, intellij-idea

The scala spark object runs good when it is run in intelliJ. But after building artifact and executing as jar, I am getting this error below.

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:org/apache/spark/sql/types/DataType

How to fix this? Appreciate your inputs on this.

**IntelliJ IDEA**:

> jar file generated by File>Project Structure>Project Setting>Artifacts> + > Jar > from modules with dependencies
>   Check Box "Include in project build" selected
>   Apply > OK
>   Tab:Build>Build Artifacts>poc:jar>Build

**Jar Error**:
[image]

**build.sbt**

```
name := "poc"
version := "0.1"
scalaVersion := "2.11.12"
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.apache.spark" % "spark-core_2.11" % "2.4.3",
  "org.apache.spark" % "spark-sql_2.11" % "2.4.3",
  "com.datastax.spark" % "spark-cassandra-connector_2.11" % "2.4.1",
  "org.apache.hadoop" % "hadoop-aws" % "2.7.1"
)
```

**poc.scala**

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.{ IntegerType, StringType, StructField, StructType}
import org.apache.spark.{SparkConf, SparkContext}
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession

object dataload {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit =
  {
    val awsAccessKeyId: String     = args(0)
    val awsSecretAccessKey: String = args(1)
    val csvFilePath: String        = args(2)
    val host: String               = args(3)
    val username: String           = args(4)
    val password: String           = args(5)
    val keyspace: String           = args(6)

    println("length args: " + args.length)

    val Conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Imp_DataMigration").setMaster("local[2]")
      .set("fs.s3n.awsAccessKeyId", awsAccessKeyId)
      .set("fs.s3n.awsSecretAccessKey", awsSecretAccessKey)
      .set("fs.s3n.impl", "org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3native.NativeS3FileSystem")
      .set("spark.cassandra.connection.host", host)
      .set("spark.cassandra.connection.port","9042")
      .set("spark.cassandra.auth.username", username)
      .set("spark.cassandra.auth.password", password)

    val sc = new SparkContext(Conf)
    val spark = SparkSession.builder.config(sc.getConf).getOrCreate()

    val schemaHdr = StructType(
      StructField("a2z_name", StringType) ::
        StructField("a2z_key", StringType) ::
        StructField("a2z_id", IntegerType) :: Nil
    )

    val df = spark.read.format( source = "csv")
      .option("header", "true")
      .option("delimiter", "\t")
      .option("quote", "\"")
      .schema(schemaHdr)
      .load( path = "s3n://at-spring/a2z.csv")

    println(df.count())

    df.write
      .format( source = "org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra")
      .option("keyspace","poc_sparkjob")
      .option("table","a2z")
      .mode(org.apache.spark.sql.SaveMode.Append)
      .save

    sc.stop()

  }


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed this issue by building a fat jar using **sbt assembly**.

This post helped me

[How to build an Uber JAR (Fat JAR) using SBT within IntelliJ IDEA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28459333/how-to-build-an-uber-jar-fat-jar-using-sbt-within-intellij-idea)

Answer (score 1):

Spark applications are typically submitted via the [spark-submit](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/submitting-applications.html) script. It is possible to to submit jobs using `java -jar ...`, but you will have a much more difficult time dealing with classpath issues, as you see to be experiencing right now.

Relatedly, you will want to mark your Spark/Hadoop dependencies as "provided", e.g. `"org.apache.spark" % "spark-core_2.11" % "2.4.3" % "provided"`, as `spark-submit` will locate and add the necessary .jar files to the classpath from your local install.

Comment: did dependencies with "provided and did "spark-submit but still the same error :(

Comment: spark-submit giving this error
   **Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: 
   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class 
   org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem not found**