# How can i implement AWS Secrets Manager on a Scala SBT Project

Tags: scala, apache-spark, sbt, aws-secrets-manager

I'm trying to implement AWS Secrets Manager on a scala project, has anyone tried it?

I have added the dependency to the project on build.sbt like this

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "com.databricks"            %% "spark-avro"         % "4.0.0",
  "com.amazonaws"             % "aws-java-sdk-core"   % "1.11.569",
  "com.amazonaws"             % "aws-java-sdk-s3"     % "1.11.569",
  "com.amazonaws"             % "aws-java-sdk-secretsmanager" % "1.11.569",
  "com.typesafe"              % "config"              % "1.3.4",
  "org.apache.spark"          %% "spark-core"         % "2.3.0" % "provided",
  "org.apache.spark"          %% "spark-sql"          % "2.3.0" % "provided",
  "org.apache.spark"          %% "spark-hadoop-cloud" % "2.3.2.3.1.0.6-1" % "provided",
  "org.apache.hadoop"         % "hadoop-common"       % "3.1.1.3.0.2.0-50" % "provided",
  "com.github.gphat"          %% "datadog-scala"      % "1.1.3" exclude ("org.json4s", "json4s-jackson") exclude ("org.json4s", "json4s-native"),
  "org.scalatest"             %% "scalatest"          % "3.0.5" % "test",
  "org.mockito"               % "mockito-core"        % "2.27.0" % "test",
  "com.github.tomakehurst"    % "wiremock-jre8"       % "2.23.2" % "test",
  "org.glassfish.jersey.core" % "jersey-common"       % "2.22.2" % "test",
  "org.glassfish.jersey.core" % "jersey-server"       % "2.22.2" % "test",
  "org.glassfish.jersey.core" % "jersey-client"       % "2.22.2" % "test"
)

assemblyMergeStrategy in assembly := {
  case PathList("META-INF", xs @ _*) =>
    xs map { _.toLowerCase } match {
      case "manifest.mf" :: Nil | "index.list" :: Nil | "dependencies" :: Nil =>
        MergeStrategy.discard
      case ps @ x :: xs if ps.last.endsWith(".sf") || ps.last.endsWith(".dsa") =>
        MergeStrategy.discard
      case "plexus" :: xs =>
        MergeStrategy.discard
      case "services" :: xs =>
        MergeStrategy.filterDistinctLines
      case "spring.com.conekta.schemas" :: Nil | "spring.handlers" :: Nil =>
        MergeStrategy.filterDistinctLines
      case _ => MergeStrategy.first
    }
```

And my implementation is like this

```
def getSecrets: Map[String,String] ={
    val secretName = "***********************"
    val endpoint = "secretsmanager.us-east-1.amazonaws.com"

    val config = new AwsClientBuilder.EndpointConfiguration(endpoint, Regions.US_EAST_1.getName)
    val clientBuilder = AWSSecretsManagerClientBuilder.standard()
    clientBuilder.setEndpointConfiguration(config)

    val client = clientBuilder.build()
    val getSecretValueRequest = new GetSecretValueRequest().withSecretId(secretName).withVersionStage("AWSCURRENT")
    val getSecretValueResult = client.getSecretValue(getSecretValueRequest)
    val secret = getSecretValueResult.getSecretString

    implicit val formats = DefaultFormats
    parse(secret).extract[Map[String, String]]
  }
```

It is working locally, but when i upload my jar to the server i'm working on i get this error:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.amazonaws.client.AwsSyncClientParams.getAdvancedConfig()Lcom/amazonaws/client/builder/AdvancedConfig;
    at com.amazonaws.services.secretsmanager.AWSSecretsManagerClient.<init>(AWSSecretsManagerClient.java:213)
    at com.amazonaws.services.secretsmanager.AWSSecretsManagerClient.<init>(AWSSecretsManagerClient.java:197)
    at com.amazonaws.services.secretsmanager.AWSSecretsManagerClientBuilder.build(AWSSecretsManagerClientBuilder.java:61)
    at com.amazonaws.services.secretsmanager.AWSSecretsManagerClientBuilder.build(AWSSecretsManagerClientBuilder.java:27)
    at com.amazonaws.client.builder.AwsSyncClientBuilder.build(AwsSyncClientBuilder.java:46)
    at com.conekta.helpers.SecretManager.getSecrets(SecretManager.scala:21)
```

Has anyone succesfuly implemented aws secret manager on a sbt project
Any help would be much apreccuated.
Thanks.

Comment: Are you building a fat jar? 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28459333/how-to-build-an-uber-jar-fat-jar-using-sbt-within-intellij-idea

Comment: yeah its a fat jar

Comment: Can you update with your full build.sbt file and the command you are using to build the jar?

Comment: i'm using

sbt assembly
to build the jar

Comment: can you use the AWS Java SDK to call secretsmanager? - This example uses  AWS SDK for Java to create a Scala application to write data in Amazon Kinesis Firehose, https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/developer/tag/scala/

Comment: @MichaelCurtis fat jar is an interesting name lol. But anyways aren't all jars fat jars using this definition - "also known as a fat JAR or JAR with dependencies—is a JAR file that contains not only a Java program, but embeds its dependencies as well" because you need the dependencies to run the java program