# IntelliJ Scala maven build jar not generating class files

Tags: scala, apache-spark, intellij-idea, maven-3

I have created spark scala(version 2.11) application and try to build using maven(version-3) using IntelliJ. At first time,able to compile and built the jar using maven successfully and able to test spark application using jar on cluster as well.Next time,I have modified some of the existing scala class code and tried to build again, code compiled and generate jar file successfully without any issues but there are no scala classes in latest jar file.I would like to know why maven build is not generating class file when I build.Can you please let me know what could be the problem and how Can I fix it ?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to build scala applications for spark is to use SBT and fat jar plugin. Details were already described there:

[How to build an Uber JAR (Fat JAR) using SBT within IntelliJ IDEA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28459333/how-to-build-an-uber-jar-fat-jar-using-sbt-within-intellij-idea)

Just don't forget to exclude spark jars from fat jar with provided.