# How to use SBT with Intellij Idea

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, sbt

I am using Scala version 2.10 and SBT version 0.13.8. To build a project I am currently executing the sbt commands through the Intellij terminal but I would like to know the use of SBT Tasks window on the right hand side of intellij idea window. Kindly have a look at the screenshot uploaded [image: here]

How can I run SBT tasks (compile, run, package) in Intellij from SBT Tasks? Is my intellij configuration correct?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22121939/how-to-execute-sbt-plugins-tasks-from-within-intellij-idea-ce

Comment: Alt+F12 (Open Terminal) -> Type: sbt -> when inside sbt you can "run", or enter "console" (REPL) or "test"

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're using an older version of IntelliJ IDEA. That the window displays "tasks" is probably a bug, because running tasks from this window is currently not supported by the Scala Plugin. I still recommend upgrading IDEA to version 2016.3, which also supports a newer version of the plugin.

Instead, you can run them from the terminal as you do now, or create a run configuration clicking on `Run -> Edit Configurations`. Then click the `+` button to add a new configuration and choose `SBT Task` from the list, and entering the tasks you would like to run.

Side note: When using sbt for your projects, the Scala version installed on the system doesn't matter. In fact, it doesn't even need to be installed.